# How can I apply a function to pairs of elements in a list with Python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of numbers and I want to find the difference of the elements in it as a percentage. Currently I am using a for loop. Is there another way, maybe using numpy ?

```
example_list = [1., 5., 4., 2., 10., 8., 3., 1.]
percentage_difference = []
for index, i in enumerate(example_list):
    if index + 1 < len(example_list):
        previous = example_list[index + 1]
        difference = round((previous - i) / previous , 3)
        percentage_difference.append(difference)
```

output explanation: (5 - 1) / 1

Comment: Add your code, and try to explain better, difference of the elements!?

Comment: -1 I don't see any example input and output nor a satisfying description of your problem.

Comment: What is this line `if index + 1 < len(example_list):`?

Comment: "the difference of the elements in it as a percentage." I have no idea what this is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) for this:

```
In [13]: import numpy as np

In [14]: a = np.array([1., 5., 4., 2., 10., 8., 3., 1.])                                         

In [15]: np.diff(a)/a[1:]                                                                        
Out[15]: 
array([ 0.8       , -0.25      , -1.        ,  0.8       , -0.25      ,                          
       -1.66666667, -2.        ])      

In [16]: np.round(np.diff(a)/a[1:], 3)
Out[16]: array([ 0.8  , -0.25 , -1.   ,  0.8  , -0.25 , -1.667, -2.   ])
```

In pure Python you can do this using `zip` with either use `map` or a list comprehension. Here's an example using `map`:

```
>>> def calculate(x_y):
    x, y = x_y
    return round((x-y)/x, 3)

>>> map(calculate, zip(lis[1:], lis[:-1]))
[0.8, -0.25, -1.0, 0.8, -0.25, -1.667, -2.0]
```

Comment: Very useful. Thanks. Is there a way to apply any function, not the specific one in question ?

Comment: @evil_inside What function? BTW I've added a pure python solutiuon as well.

Comment: The pure python solution covers my any function question. In my mind I had using something like lambda.

Comment: @evil_inside Yes, you can also use an inline lambda here. Note that `map` is usually slower when used with lambda.

Answer (score 1):

With numpy and slices

```py
import numpy as np
example_list = np.array([1., 5., 4., 2., 10., 8., 3., 1.])
percentage_difference=np.round((example_list[1:]-example_list[:-1])/example_list[1:],3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I not sure if you want the (5,4) grouping to be -0.2 or -0.25 so his is both in that order

```
b = [(a[i+1] - x)/float(x) for i,x in enumerate(a[:-1:])]
>>> [4.0, -0.2, -0.5, 4.0, -0.2, -0.625, -0.6666666666666666]

b = [(a[i+1] - x)/float(a[i+1]) for i,x in enumerate(a[:-1:])]
>>> [0.8, -0.25, -1.0, 0.8, -0.25, -1.6666666666666667, -2.0]
```